# How to fix an extensive echoing while recording audio using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, html5-audio

So, I am working on a small electron desktop app that captures desktop screen and records video and audio.
When I am trying to add audio to the stream it starts echoing really badly and I am not sure why.

I am using:

- Windows 10 PRO 18362.778
- Chrome 81.0.4044.113
- Electron 8.2.3

Here is some code.

I create these constraints when I want to capture and record video only:

```
const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I pass is to the stream like that:

`const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`

It works like a charm. However when I start adding audio it gives me echo:

```
const constraints = {
        audio: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            }
        },
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I can't just set the audio to true. It then gives me this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error starting screen capture

An interesting fact. When I go to [Mozilla documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints/audio) on audio constraints and use the demo button it gives me echo too. I tried doing it on Edge and the result was better, but still had echo. So can it be the audio codec?

[Here](https://blog.addpipe.com/audio-constraints-getusermedia/?fbclid=IwAR1A2z-r2chUhg7GeqY6kZ7z4f_lo9ZBnHhTqz4wTcFSUV_RayRb0-MaQ7A) it says that echoCancellation constraint is supported and on by default starting Chrome version 62.

[Here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4776?fbclid=IwAR3zytbn9EF8MtV6L9zEslUnbhXWT1qAY0KlqNDQexSnp7tfMfLPC5avld8) is the branch on the Github where I tried to find solution, but failed.

[Here](https://github.com/Eldersonar/Electron-sandbox/tree/master/screen%20recorder/screen-recorder) is my git repo if you want to look at it more closely.

PS: this is my first post here. Let me know if I did something wrong here and can improve the post. Thank you!

Comment: Update. The Chrome version is 80.0.3987.163

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem comes from attempting to initiate a single stream of your microphone audio and computer screen video at the same time. To fix this issue, you will need to create an audio stream first, then separately create a video stream that captures your computer screen, and finally, combine the streams into one.

```
// create audio and video constraints
const constraintsVideo = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
        }
    }
}
const constraintsAudio = {audio: true}

// create audio and video streams separately
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintsAudio)
const videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintsVideo)

// combine the streams 
const combinedStream = new MediaStream([...videoStream.getVideoTracks(), ...audioStream.getAudioTracks()])
```

After you combine the streams, you can use `combinedStream` as if it originated as a single stream.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That works really well. I wish there is better documentation on using WebRTC with examples.

Comment: Great answer, Alex, thanks. Could you elaborate a bit on why this works and where is the difference?

Comment: Even the webrtc.org website provides an example with audio: true, video: true (webrtc.org/getting-started/media-devices#using-asyncawait)... I tried your solution but I keep having echo... I think I can fix it by setting the srcObject property of <video> html element to the audioStream, instead to the combinedStream

Comment: I implemented this solution as well and the echo is persisting.

Comment: @user2010955 Did you ever solve your issue?

Answer (score 7):

I think the easy fix here would be to add a muted element to the playback on your page.

```
 // Preview the source in a video element
    videoElement.srcObject = stream
    videoElement.muted = true
    videoElement.play()
```

That will work in all browsers and you'll still record the audio.

Comment: I just tried that solution and the app will not record the sound with the muted element.

Comment: Hey, Doug. I'll also up your answer since it partially correct. However, I was able to record only system audio, not the mic.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, such a cleaver idea!

Answer (score 2):

A very late answer I know, but I was trying to understand your issue, because I'm currently dealing with echo cancelling issues via WebRTC in regards to desktop capturing and I was wondering why your initial approach (adding `chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'` as a `mandatory` constraint to video and audio) causes echo, because this is the correct usage, as described in the Electron docs. I don't think that post which is marked as the correct answer, really solves the problem. Instead the second answer is correct in this case. The problem is not related to the usage of the constraints / streams. The reason you are hearing echo is, that you are adding the captured audio to your speaker output implicitly again, by assigning it to the `<video>` element. This creates the echoing loop. To avoid this, the correct solution is to mute the `<video>` element like you did in your repo. I tried your code and recording works fine (also with the muted `<video>` element), when re-enabling the code section which captures video/audio at once (via the constraint mentioned above).